# XSLT Select tag with starts-with() fails on numeric values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I'm having problems with numeric value when using a select condition with `starts-with()`

```
<Load>
    <DataArea>
        <tag>
            <row>01,Header</row>
        </tag>
    </DataArea>
</Load>
```

Originally it is `<row>A,Header</row>`

When  Ireplaced it with 01, it failed and I get a **Qname invalid** message.
Any ideas?

Below is the xslt line.

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(Load/DataArea/tag[starts-with(row, '01,')], ',') " />
```

I know  there's something missing here but I can't figure out.

Thank you.

Comment: tried this in xslt online tester, its working fine.

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced using the posted code: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYjb

Comment: I think the failure isn't in the piece of code you have shown us, it is elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry for this post guys, I found the problem. It was on a separate block of code where element name set is 01 which is invalid. Please vote to close the question.